# In Outlook VSTO development, how to obtain the EntryID of the currently replied/forwarded email based on the draft reply/forwarded email?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, mailitem

In Outlook VSTO development, I would like to know how to obtain the EntryID of the currently replied or forwarded email based on the Outlook.MailItem object of the obtained draft email in the scenario of replying or forwarding a draft email?

I have compared that when viewing emails in the Inspector, the EntryID value can be obtained through the MailItem object, but when replying or forwarding, I don’t know how to get the EntryID of the currently replied/forwarded email?

What I expect is to obtain the EntryID of the currently replied or forwarded email in some way when replying/forwarding a draft email.

I'm hoping someone can answer my question, I'd be grateful!

Comment: I have found ConversationIndex and ConversationTopic.
But I don't know how to use them to get the original email of this reply/forward.

Comment: So you are asking fro about how to obtain the entry id of the message once it is sent and moved to the Sent Items folder?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide such information out of the box. You need to implement the solution where you could track all opened or selected items in Outlook and track for the `Reply` or `Forward` events, so you could get the required information from the original item.

You may find the [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) article helpful.